# Subquery within a select statement when creating a view

Tags: sql, select, view

I am needing to create a view as we are migrating our data into a new system.  In creating this view I am needing to create a subquery where the table references back on itself to pull parent organization information.  I have created the query as a stand alone and it works fine, but when I put it into the view and do a select * on the view I get the error message "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Below is my current View Creation statement.

```
CREATE view [dbo].[Altai_V_Account] as
SELECT cast(N.ID as nvarchar) as altai_legacymemberid,
      RTRIM (n.company) as name,
      RTRIM (cd.aha) as aha_memberID,
      RTRIM (n.member_type) as altai_base_customertypeid,
      RTRIM (na.ADDRESS_1) as address1_line1,
      RTRIM (na.ADDRESS_2) as address1_line2,
      RTRIM (na.city) as address1_city,
      RTRIM (na.state_province) as address1_stateorprovince,
      RTRIM (na.zip) as address1_postalcode,
      RTRIM (n.Fax) as fax,
      RTRIM (n.WORK_PHONE) as telephone1,
      RTRIM (cd.FTE) as numberofemployees,
      RTRIM (n.co_id) as ParentAccountID,
      RTRIM (n.website) as websiteurl,
      RTRIM (cd.LICENSED_BEDS) as gha_bedcalculation,
      (select CompN.COMPANY
          From Name as n inner join Name as CompN on n.CO_ID=CompN.ID
              Where n.CO_ID=CompN.id
              and n.STATUS='A'
             and (n.MEMBER_TYPE ='HCE'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE ='I'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE ='SA'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE ='SI'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE ='SM'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE ='SPON'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE ='SYS'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE ='VP'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE ='VPA'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE ='ASC'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE = 'C'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE = 'HCS'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE = 'NH'
                    or n.MEMBER_TYPE = 'NMI')) as parentaccount


FROM Name as N
    inner join Company_Demo as cd on N.id=cd.ID
    inner join Name_Address as na on N.ID=NA.ID
WHERE N.MEMBER_TYPE ='HCE'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE ='I'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE ='SA'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE ='SI'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE ='SM'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE ='SPON'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE ='SYS'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE ='VP'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE ='VPA'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE ='ASC'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE = 'C'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE = 'HCS'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE = 'NH'
 or N.MEMBER_TYPE = 'NMI'
 and na.STATUS='A'
```

Thanks!

Update:  I am not a "SQL" person, but we don't have one in our organization.  I am basically using a code example provided to me by the company doing our migration.  I don't know why the name table is called name, the designers of the software we are using currently named it that way.

For this particular subquery, the record list the parent company's ID number (co_ID), but not the name of the company.  I was wanting the query to see the CO_ID field and then pull the company name affiliate with that ID.  It works as a normal query, just not as a subquery.

Comment: That's definitly a strange query. You are accessing the same table thrice, which is probably avoidable. And you trim all fields, even IDs, where I wonder why they were even allowed into the database when the spaces bother you. And you use hard-coded values for member types where you should get that group better from some table instead. At last the subquery isn't related to the main query, thus selecting always the same value. In your case value**s** rather, which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: `Name` is a strange name for a table. What does it contain? Companies? Then why isn't it called `Company` instead for instance? And it is hierarchical (recursive) somehow? Why? What do the levels represent? Is there a maximum number of levels in the hierarchy? It might help if you explained what your query is supposed to do, so we could give you some advice on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that when you are using sub query in place of column, it should return scalar result. That is it should return one row and one column.

In your case, the sub query will be returning multiple rows or columns. Please try the sub query separately first to check if its retuning a scalar value.